# Finding a minima of the weighted energy function

Tags: derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

From the proof of Theorem 8 in [Hashimoto et al. 2016](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Q16-1020.pdf), I hardly don't understand a small thing about the minima of the weighted energy function.

Consider the objective,

$$\min_{\lambda_{ij}} \;C_{ij} \log \left( \frac{\exp(-\lambda_{ij})}{\sum_k\exp(-\lambda_{ik})} \right)$$

for scalar values $C_{ij}$ and $\lambda_{ij}$.

Then the minima of the objective is given as $\lambda_{ij}^* = -\log(C_{ij}) + a_i$ with un-identifiable value $a_i$ by differentiation.

My question is how we can obtain the minima like that by differentiation.
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Substitute $\lambda_{ij} = x$ to get $f(x) = A \log (\frac{e^{-x}} {e^{-x} + K}) = A \log (\frac{1} {1 + Ke^x}) = - A \log (1 + Ke^x) $. You could easily differentiate this function.

Comment: @Kaind, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -A \frac{K e^x}{1 + K e^x}$. And, it seems that I can't find the local minima by setting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  < 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. There is no explicit constraint on $x$ in the paper.

Comment: Does $A$ or $K$ depend on $x$ from the paper?

Comment: @Kaind, Nope, I guess it actually minimizes on $$\min_{\lambda_{ij}} \;\sum_j \;C_{ij} \log \left( \frac{\exp(-\lambda_{ij})}{\sum_k\exp(-\lambda_{ik})} \right)$$. In this case, it seems valid. There would be a mistake in writing.

Comment: In that case $f(x) = -A_j \log(1 + K_je^x) - \sum_{i \neq j} A_i \log (e^{-x} + K_i) + C$.